# Integrating PayPal .NET SDK into website without using PayPal button

Tags: asp.net-mvc, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-webhooks

We've implemented the above as follows:

We're integrating [PayPal .NET SDK](http://Integrating%20PayPal%20.NET%20SDK%20into%20website%20without%20using%20PayPal%20button) with a public website without using PayPal's built-in Buttons (Buy Now etc.). The process flow is as follows:

1. User clicks on a regular ASP.NET MVC button that calls an Action method that creates a payment object with all necessary properties set (transactions, urls, amount, quantity etc.).
2. The above action method calls necessary PayPal .NET SDK APIs, connects to PayPal that displays its own page where user logs in, verifies the amount displayed, approves it by clicking their submit button
3. PayPal - after approving it- sends a response back where we perform our some back-office tasks and if everything goes OK our "Payment Successful" pages gets displayed.

Note: Our code is using PayPal's [Webhook](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest/webhooks/)  functionality as well.

**Question**: We've tested the above process on PayPal's SandBox and it works fine. Are we missing something and/or PayPal's Built-in button ("Buy Now" etc.) is necessary? The application is for selling one single item (a digital download) at a time.

Comment: Do you use proper key to authenticate you request?

Comment: @ZamronyP.Juhara Yes I do. In their sample project [here](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK) they use configuration class to get `var apiContext = PayPalConfiguration.GetAPIContext();` etc. e.g: `string accessToken = new OAuthTokenCredential
             (ClientId, ClientSecret, GetConfig()).GetAccessToken();`. In `asspsettings.json` we've set clientId, clientSecret etc. I Pass in a `APIContext` object to `authenticate` the call and to send a unique request id (that ensures idempotency). The SDK generates a request id if you do not pass one explicitly. Is that what you're referring to?

Answer (score 0):

According to the PayPal [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/)  the buttons are just default and the most stable flow.

> PayPal Checkout gives your buyers a simplified and secure checkout experience that keeps them local to your website or mobile app throughout the payment process.

But in real world 'PayPal Smart Payment Buttons' seems to be just the most straightforward way to implement PayPal behavior in your website. Furthermore, most of the greatest PayPals clients (like Netflix, Google play or Spotify) don't use them. Mostly they provide their own buttons with additional logic.

So, I guess that there is nothing wrong in avoiding PayPal default "recommended" buttons. Just make sure your end-2-end payment flow is working correctly.